# wpf how to get codebehind variable on the XAML

Tags: wpf, code-behind

in code behind we set the imagepath of window background ,is there any way to get this value on the xaml and use it to set the background image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the best case, the code behind is empty or just InitializeComponent is there.

Therefore I will highlight a way of accomplishing this and let changes in the
future become very easy!

You can easily set a DataContext for your Window (for example in the codebehind).

From this DataContext (which should implement INotifyPropertyChanged when this
path will change) you can easily bind to whatever you want.

Here is a small example:

```
// ViewModel class containing ImagePath

public class WindowBackgroundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}


// in Codebehind
public WindowBackgroundViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

// in Constructor
public myWindow()
{
    this.ViewModel = new WindowBackgroundViewModel();
    this.ViewModel.ImagePath = @"C:\myBackground.png";

    this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
}


// in XAML
<...  ImageBackground="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Though i am not showing with background image, but still the following binding should be valid for your case:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}" 
 Text="{Binding MyProperty}" Width="200" Height="50"/>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyProperty = "Sample";
        }
    }
```

Hope this should help you!